# Entity Framework query using navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework

Users have many Roles. Roles have many Privileges. I need to get a list of privileges assigned to user based on roles user may have. I have something like this in mind but it gives me an IEnumerable of IEnumerable of Privilege:

```
List<Privilege> privileges = user.Roles.Select(r=>r.Privileges.Where(p=>p.IsActive));
```

How can I do this using navigation properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SelectMany
```

It flattens the ienumerables as you go

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
user.Roles.SelectMany(r => r.Privileges).Where(p=>p.IsActive).ToList();
```